# use an empty {} to initialize a vector is different?

Tags: c++, stl

I see some people tend to initialize a vector with an empty {}, and I wonder whether it is different from directly initialize with the default constructor?

for example:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> vec;
    vector<int> vec2 {};

    cout << sizeof(vec) << " " << sizeof(vec2) << endl; // 24 24
    cout << vec.size() << " " << vec2.size() << endl;   // 0 0 
}
```

and I check its assembly code, and it shows that initializing a vector with an empty {} generate more code(https://godbolt.org/z/2BAWU_).

[Assembly code screen shot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hy4EP.png)

I am quite new to C++ language, and I would be grateful if someone could help me out.

Comment: I suspect you are comparing unoptimized assembly code, which isn't a very interesting scenario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using braces is [value initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization). Not using them is [default initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization). As somebody alluded to in the comments, they should generate the exact same code when optimizations are turned on for `vector`. There's a notable difference with built-in types like pointers and `int`; there default initialization does nothing, while value initialization sets them to `nullptr` and zero, respectively.